# how does photomath implement an instant latex preview?

Tags: editors, preview

how does photomath expert implement an instant latex preview? is there an app/software that does the same? i tried a lot of latex editors and they all need to be manually recompiled and much slower.

equation editor++ have the same preview feature but for only a very small space and there is a delay too.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: assuming you mean [this](https://photomath.com/en/arithmetic/evaluating-powers) it is [tag:mathjax] so javascript not tex doing the math layout

Comment: i see. it's cuz photomath keeps referring to it as latex, that i was confused. Seems like ive been looking at the wrong stuff.

Comment: well, i found something useful like matcha.io